# three.js change path for tube while rendering

Tags: javascript, three.js, morphing

My approach include these steps:

1) create initial path for tube (array of positions of points)

2) render tube based on path

3) change path array

4) go to step 2

So, perhaps I need functions like these:

```
function morphPath(path){
// some magic here
return newPath;
}

function morphTube(path){
// change tube's vertices positions based on path
}
```

Let's say I want to render a snake that crawling around.

I found beautiful and very complicated for me example, please give me basic understanding for how to solve my issue.

Example - http://codepen.io/tdhooper/full/ZGPOQJ/

I use this function to create tube:

```
var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry( curve, 10, 3, 20, false );
```

Please, suggest me which function to use for curve creation and how to morph (not scale, not rotate, not translate tube)?

My array of points is simple:

```
points = [{ x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}, { x: 1, y: 1, z: 0}, { x: 3, y: 0, z: 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you create any instance of any kind of Geometry in THREE.js, the created instance has a property named 'vertices'. In your particular case, a Cilinder Geometry creates lots of vertices based on the original points (Vector3) array you provided when creating the curve.

So, i think you can create a new path each time you want to morph. Then, for morphTube, create a new cylinder geometry based on the path you created and either dispose the geometry from the mesh that is being rendered and attach the new geometry (this can sometimes be tricky) or you can copy each vertex from the cylinder geometry you just created to the cylinder geometry atached to the mesh.